# installing agda fails on duplicate instance declarations

Tags: agda

I'm trying to give agda a shot, but I can't get it installed. I'm running GHC 7.8.3 in a cabal sandbox.

```
Failed to install Agda-2.4.0.1
Build log ( /Users/jsnavely/project/agda/.cabal-sandbox/logs/Agda-2.4.0.1.log ):
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/dh/ckhr9p0j3kq3bx12176p7rlw0000gn/T/Agda-2.4.0.1-77992/Agda-2.4.0.1/dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/dh/ckhr9p0j3kq3bx12176p7rlw0000gn/T/Agda-2.4.0.1-77992/Agda-2.4.0.1/dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/dh/ckhr9p0j3kq3bx12176p7rlw0000gn/T/Agda-2.4.0.1-77992/Agda-2.4.0.1/dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/setup/setup ...
Configuring Agda-2.4.0.1...
Building Agda-2.4.0.1...
Preprocessing library Agda-2.4.0.1...
[  1 of 272] Compiling Agda.Utils.Maybe.Strict ( src/full/Agda/Utils/Maybe/Strict.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/build/Agda/Utils/Maybe/Strict.o )
[  2 of 272] Compiling Agda.Utils.SemiRing ( src/full/Agda/Utils/SemiRing.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/build/Agda/Utils/SemiRing.o )
[  3 of 272] Compiling Agda.TypeChecking.Monad.Debug ( src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Monad/Debug.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/build/Agda/TypeChecking/Monad/Debug.o )
[  4 of 272] Compiling Agda.Utils.Cluster ( src/full/Agda/Utils/Cluster.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-eeb4211c/build/Agda/Utils/Cluster.o )

src/full/Agda/Utils/Cluster.hs:50:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Monad m => Functor (EquivT s x y m)
        -- Defined at src/full/Agda/Utils/Cluster.hs:50:10
      instance Functor m => Functor (EquivT s c v m)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Equivalence.Monad’
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Agda-2.4.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I'd be happy to unpack the cabal package, but I'm not sure what I'd fiddle with. Can we remove one of the definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `equivalence` library ([hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/equivalence-0.2.5)) didn't define `Functor` instance for `EquivT` and for that reason Agda defined its own. The latest versions (0.2.4 and later) added this missing instance and there is now conflict with the Agda one.

You have basically two choices: either downgrade to `equivalence-0.2.3` or remove the instance from Agda source files. I checked and the implementations match. However, the Agda one comes with different constraints (as can be seen from the error message):

```
instance Monad   m => Functor (EquivT s x y m)  -- Agda
instance Functor m => Functor (EquivT s c v m)  -- equivalence
```

So, while the instance can be safely removed, it is possible (although unlikely) that there will be some broken type class constraints - for example a type with a `Monad` instance but without a `Functor` one.

Also consider reporting this problem on the [official bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/list). As far as I can tell, it hasn't been reported yet.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is fixed in the git(hub) version of Agda.  The fix will be released with 2.4.0.2.